# Selendroid enter infinite loop when trying to start session

Tags: java, android, maven, selendroid

I was trying to start a tutorial with Selendroid, using maven. But it turns into an infinite loop when parsing the desired capabilities into JSONObjects in `io.selendroid.standalone.server.handler.CreateSessionHandler line 43` : `return new SelendroidResponse(sessionID, new JSONObject(caps.asMap()))`.

The issue occurs in `new JSONObject(caps.asMap())`, it starts mapping objects into JSONObject, but when it comes to an object of type `org.openqa.selenium.Platform`, it fails to map it and a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` is thrown.

I tried to reproduce it, so I wrote this single line of code that fails `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Platform.ANY);` , I am not sure if the issue is related to Jackson, selendroid and a manipulation on mine. I wonder if anyone came across this and was able to solve it.

```java
package org.mel.selendroid.base;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String...strings){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Platform.ANY);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Please note that I searched in the Web and stackoverflow, but without luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the parent tag in my pom.xml which was referring to spring-boot-starter-parent.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```